# Error calling variables from method class

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py-modules

Am working on a simple game/app. When I call a variable on `web2py` view, I get this error:

```
quack= duck.quack()
TypeError: unbound method quack() must be called with duck instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

my codes are here:
In the module

```
from gluon import *
class duck():
    def quack():
        return 'Quacks like a duck'
    def walk():
        return 'Walks like a person'
```

In the controller

```
def data_filters():
    fils = duck.quack()
    return dict(fils=fils)
```

In the view:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=fils}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you need to create an instance of your class if you want to use its methods.

```
class duck():
    def quack(self):

#...

x = duck()
fils = x.quack()
```

However, if the method doesn't need to refer to `self` or any attributes of the object, you can mark it as a static method and continue using `duck.quack()` as you are now.

```
class duck():
    @staticmethod
    def quack():
        #...
```